# How does last authorize.net changes refer to CiviCRM

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, authorize.net

Lately I have received email stating that a few things are changing in Authorize.net payment. Among a few items (changing urls, longer ids, tls 1.1 force etc) one is:

> **RC4 Cipher Disablement** 
>   In an effort to ensure that all of your server-to-server communications with the Authorize.Net platform (both
>   transactional and otherwise) maintain the highest levels of security,
>   we will be disabling the RC4 cipher suite during the first half of
>   2016. A follow-up notification will be sent out once specific dates for the disablement are ready for the sandbox and production
>   environments.
>
> For now, if you have a solution that relies on RC4 to communicate with
>   our servers, please update it to a current, high-security cipher as
>   soon as possible. Please review our API best practices blog post for
>   more information.

I haven't been able to find anything mentioning rc4 in civicrm authorize.net payment processor. Does anyone know if this relates to CiviCRM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, this has a lot more to do with your web server and the cypher suites that are configured than it does with CiviCRM directly.  SSLLabs has a great page on getting all of that set up.

https://www.ssllabs.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you can see more details about this at: https://civicrm.org/blog/yashodha/are-you-ready-for-tls-12-update-cant-escape-it